# How to make the dropdown options alphabetical using html, vue, js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

In JavaScript, an options list is populated from a database.

Is there a way to sort it alphabetically?

Comment: use order by in your select query

Comment: or you can order when you get list in front-end.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out before, the ideal case would be to retrieve your array sorted from the backend, usually this is more efficient.

In case you still want to do it from the front end after you retrieve you array apply a sort, in the example below I am doing it at the mounted stage, but tailor this to your actual needs

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myOptionsArray: ['W','E','R','A','D', 'B']
  },
  mounted() {
    this.myOptionsArray = this.myOptionsArray.sort();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <select name="mySelect">
      <option v-for="(item , index) in myOptionsArray" v-bind:key="index">
        {{item}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: sort is undefined

Comment: sort() is a prototype function so if the array exist and has contents it should be available https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort , can you post your code to understand what might be the issue

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient way would be ordering them in the backend during the query. totally depends on your usecase. Elseway you should sort it in the frontend by using the

```
key = "Key you want to sort on"
<List of database>.sort((a,b)=>a[key] - b[key])
```